# join в mysql

Tags: mysql

Господа, я сделал таблицу "турниры"
в которой есть столбцы "id победителя", "название турнира", "призовой фонд"
эта таблица связана с другой таблицей, "победители"
в таблице "победители" есть "id победителя" и "его имя"

мне нужен запрос, в результате которого было бы 3 столбца
"название турнира" и "призовой фонд" из таблицы "турниры"
и еще "имя победителя" из таблицы "победители"
­
как это сделать в одном запросе с помощью join?
ну или в нескольких, но все через sql?
­

Но если бы я программировал я бы сделал циклом от 1 до 10, к примеру, и эти значения от 1 до 10 подставлялись бы в переменную.
тогда запросы были бы:

```
SELECT `Tourney_Name`, `Prize_Pool` FROM `tourney` WHERE `id_Winner` = переменная
SELECT `Name` FROM `winner` WHERE `id_Winner` = переменная
```

понимаю .что это лишние нагрузки, как оптимизировать, как сделать с помощью join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не особо спец в запросах, но JOIN тут, на мой взгляд, не особо нужен:

```
SELECT 
    t1.`Tourney_Name`, t1.`Prize_Pool`, t2.`Name` 
FROM
    `tourney` t1, `winner` t2
WHERE 
    t1.`id_Winner` = '$user_id' AND t2.`id_Winner` = '$user_id'
GROUP BY 
    t2.`Name`
```

Потестировал с JOIN и без. В первом случае запрос выполнялся в среднем за 0.0018 сек., во втором за 0.0008 сек. Но повторю, что я не гуру в SQL-запросах, поэтому не спешите делать окончательные выводы. Вот на всякий пожарный вариант с JOIN:

```
SELECT 
  t1.`Tourney_Name`,
  t1.`Prize_Pool`,
  t2.`Name`
FROM
  `tourney` t1
  INNER JOIN `winner` t2 ON (t1.`id_Winner` = t2.`id_Winner`)
WHERE
  t1.`id_Winner` = t2.`id_Winner` AND 
  t2.`id_Winner` = '$user_id'
GROUP BY 
    t2.`Name`
```

P.S. Одно не понял - что вы имели в виду, говоря о циклах?

> я бы сделал циклом от 1 до 10

Если имелось в виду, что сразу несколько пользователей надо вытаскивать, то тогда
можно сделать так: ... `id_Winner` IN ($user_id_1, $user_id_2, $user_id_N) ...